# MVC3 Razor not recognizing when to stop parsing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, conditional-statements

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    @if (ViewBag.VerifyIfLoggedIn) {

        $("#needlogin-popup").dialog({
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            minHeight: 384,
            minWidth: 596,
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: 'slide',
                duration: 500,
                direction: 'up'
            },
            hide: {
                effect: 'slide',
                duration: 250,
                direction: 'up'
            },
            title: 'Inicie Sesion'
        });
    }
});
```

If something is true, then output this Javascript code to the page.

But I'm getting the error:

> CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

How can I tell Razor to stop parsing and output whatever is in the conditional statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `<text>...</text>` around the code.

Read on how it works here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

> The  tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It
>   causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the  block as
>   content, and to not render the containing  tag element (meaning
>   only the inner contents of the  element will be rendered – the
>   tag itself will not).
>
> This makes it convenient when you want to render multi-line content
>   blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    @if (ViewBag.VerifyIfLoggedIn) { 
        <text>$("#needlogin-popup").dialog({ 
            modal: true, 
            closeOnEscape: true, 
            minHeight: 384, 
            minWidth: 596, 
            resizable: false, 
            show: { 
                effect: 'slide', 
                duration: 500, 
                direction: 'up' 
            }, 
            hide: { 
                effect: 'slide', 
                duration: 250, 
                direction: 'up' 
            }, 
            title: 'Inicie Sesion' 
        }); </text>
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue for me. Weird, but it solved it.

Comment: @SergioTapia - why is it weird?  That's why the tags exist.

Comment: Seems clunky in comparison to the very concise `@` keyword.

Comment: @SergioTapia - It's a lot less clunkly than prefixing each line with `@:` which is the only other way to do it.  But you would have to do it on each line.